# How to remove index.php from url slim framework setting VirtualHost?

Tags: php, .htaccess, centos, virtualhost, slim

reference image:

[image]

In this route I have the example:

```
C:\wamp\www\api
```

I work with centos in VirtualBox.

In the console of centos I can get into the same folder with this route:

```
cd /var/www/html/sistemaTareas/api
```

Well, in API folder I have:

```
index.php | .htaccess | Slim
```

Index.php:

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoLoader();
$application = new \Slim\Slim();
$application->get('/hello/:firstname/:lastname', function ($firstname,$lastname) {
echo "hola, $firstname $lastname";
});
$application->run();
?>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  !/src/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ src/$1 [L]
```

If I put this in Chrome:

```
http://localhost:8082/sistemaTareas/api/index.php/hello/jean/bergeret
```

Print this:

```
hola, jean bergeret
```

I need print this :

```
hola, jean bergeret
```

But with this URL (without index.php):

```
http://localhost:8082/sistemaTareas/api/hello/jean/bergeret
```

The VirtualHost in httpd.conf:

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerAdmin me@mysite.com
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/sistemaTareas/api"
#ServerName mysite.com
#ServerAlias www.mysite.com

#ErrorLog "logs/mysite.com-error.log"
#CustomLog "logs/mysite.com-access.log" combined

#<Directory "/var/www/html/sistemaTareas/api">
#   AllowOverride All
#   Order allow,deny
#   Allow from all
#</Directory>
```

For now is commented, but if I uncomment VirtualHost and I use :

```
http://localhost:8082/sistemaTareas/api/hello/jean/bergeret
```

print "not found".

I guess the virtualhost is the problem, so how can I configure it to work without index.php?
(sorry my english)

Comment: TL;DR - Can you sum it up in a question. It's just not clear.

Comment: why you say that?. mm I need the example works without index.php.

Comment: Is `index.php` defined as a default document?

Comment: Amm no, i create that.

Comment: By default, Apache should see it as a default document. When calling a directory in the URL, the server will then look for that document title by default, IE when no file has been specific in the URL. So that would be something to check in your config files.

Comment: Your .htaccess seems incorrect, as there is no `src` folder in your reference image

Answer (score 0):

Configure your VirtualHost like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "XXX"
  ServerName XXX
  ServerAlias XXX

  <Directory "XXX">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog "XXX"
</VirtualHost>
```

And in the base of my project i have an .htaccess file with :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thats's all and it work for me :)