# Slim rewrite route not working

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, slim

I set my virtual host document directory to my public folder
so it's working fine when I use localhost\hello,
the hello route will be initial.

for some reason, I need to set extra path name galaxy which is actually point to public folder too.

so I set a alias /galaxy "my public folder path"

then when I try localhost\galaxy\hello, it will show up 404
but if I try localhost\galaxy\index.php\hello it works

so what do I didn't setup, so I can use localhost\galaxy\hello just like local\hello without typing index.php ?

thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Point all requests to index.php in your http server's virtual host settings.

You don't necessarily have to use an alias in this case. You could simply create a route group called galaxy, and place all subsequent routes under that group.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is due to your .htaccess file.

Try creating .htaccess file in your galaxy directory with the following

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

If this doesn't work try looking into [the requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30089230/how-to-remove-index-php-from-url-slim-framework-setting-virtualhost) for vhosts

Comment: Note that for reasonably recent versions of Apache `FallbackResource /index.php` is all that's needed instead of starting a rewrite engine.